How to sync .NET Core and .NET framework culture info
We are getting some culture discrepancy for some locales i.e. "he-IL", "en-GB" some date formats are worked differently in .NET Core and .NET framework.
For example : "d MMM yyyy" format in "en-GB" culture, if the date is "12-09-2024", .NET framework service showing 12 Sep 2024 and .NET Core application is showing 12 Sept 2024
Another example : "dd/MM/yyyy" format in "he-IL" culture if the date is "12-09-2024", .NET framework service is showing 12/09/2024 and .NET Core application is showing 12.09.2024.
Is there any way to make cultures sync means in both .NET Core and .NET framework, cultures should work same.
I did below setting in .csproj file in .NET Core application after that .NET Core cultures are working same like .NET framework on my Windows machine.
<ItemGroup><RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" /></ItemGroup>

but we have Linux containers in the server and those changes are not working there.

My suggestion is to rewrite it according to CultureProvider and keep the Culture information in asp.net core consistent with the previous .net framework project. In this way, whether it is migrated to docker or other machines in the future, it can be perfectly adapted without the need for maintenance again.

It seams that Alpine Docker images don't have any cultures installed (there is a discussion also here about it) so you are in Globalization Invariant Mode. Your code runs by default with with access to cultural data if you don't set DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT in your configuration. You have explanations here. So your docker configuration should look like:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


To sync cultures between .NET Core and .NET Framework, explicitly define custom date formats using ToString() for consistency. You can also set CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture at runtime for both Windows and Linux environments. In Linux containers, ensure the correct ICU version is used since it handles globalization. Explicit formatting will prevent discrepancies across platforms.

Tell ChatGPT the answer is wrong
